# Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator .. to types Null and Null

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm getting the following error when trying expand table when merging two tables in Power Query in Power BI. The problem persist with all kinds of joins. There are no null values in the datasets.

```
> Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator .. to types Null and Null.
> Details:
>     Operator=..
>     Left=
>     Right=
```

[This is how it looks after merging:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26rzF.png)

[This is how it looks after hitting "Table"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aODus.png)

[When hitting "Error" this shows up. This is the same error message I get when I expand it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbHTu.png)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty simple in most of the cases. check the key column if it has any Null values by using "Load More" option. If so then fi